# What can we do about incorrect tag wiki edits that get approved?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits, tag-wiki, tag-excerpt

I was going back over my review history and found that I had voted contrary to the majority on [this edit to the objective-c tag wiki excerpt](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9586927). Now anybody who has developed iOS apps in any language other than Swift and Objective-C can tell you that the edit is factually wrong, but in addition, it's also irrelevant info to have in the tag excerpt. The edit was approved in the review queue, but then rolled back the next day by 
[Josh Caswell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/603977/josh-caswell). Good on him - if the story ended here, I wouldn't be posting to meta.

I was curious to see if erroneous edits have been approved for the tag in the past, so I went through the [edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/3625129/revisions) for the [objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/objective-c) tag excerpt, and I learned that Josh Caswell has rolled back changes on four separate bad edits [1](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1181827) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2607286) [3](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7422315) [4](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9586927), **the second of which did nothing except to introduce incorrect grammar and break references to other tags**.

---

Now if this is happening on this tag, I can only imagine it is happening on other tags as well. I feel like from now on if I reject a bad tag edit, I should bookmark it so I can roll it back on the off chance that it gets accepted.

First of all, is this something that anyone else has noticed happening in other tags? (Or is the [objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/objective-c) tag somehow a magnet for bad edits and this isn't a problem for other tag wikis?) If so, then how can we help alleviate this problem? I don't want us to all have to "adopt a tag" like Josh Caswell so that we can monitor it and revert bad edits.

Perhaps we could separate the Suggested Edits review queue into Suggested Edits and Suggested Tag Edits, so that users don't review tag edits unless they specifically seek them out (and hopefully have more knowledge of the tag system)? And/or maybe we could restrict tag edit reviews to >10k rep? (Although with >10k there may not be enough volunteers to review tag edits).

Does this look like a problem in need of a solution, or is it okay to just rely on >20k users to roll back bad tag edits when they happen? Looking forward to hearing what you think.

Comment: Yeah, I keep my eye on that excerpt in the (probably futile) hope that the tag will be used a bit more correctly. It would be nice if this was not a strictly manual process.

Comment: Thanks for voting correctly on that suggested edit review, by the way.

Comment: Tag wiki edit approval already requires 5k rep, so not every edit reviewer can approve them. But apparently, not everyone with 5k rep can be trusted. This is a disturbing reality.

Comment: @jpmc26 any rep based threshold will grow less effective at gating something to top users with time because the minimum rep/year threshold goes down making it easier for long term users to slack their way to it.  The two tag wiki related badges probably make it worse by encouraging people to make dubious edits in the first place.

Comment: @DanNeely Yup. Still sad, though.